# Mesh covers other mesh

Tags: mesh

I am modelling a head in Blender and since I projected the details of the original mesh I just noticed that the eyeballs I made are kind of covered by the head itself, even tho they should be visible. Here's what I mean (I moved the eyeball out of the eyesocket a little so it is more visible what I mean):
[image]
[image]
[image]
With the original map the eyes are totally fine:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that you haven't enabled the In Front option for the head in the Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the *In Front* option for the head in the *Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display*.